# UIScrollView unintended content displacement in landscape mode

Tags: uiscrollview, height, offset

I' ran into an absolutely weird kind of problem I don't have a clue yet how to fix it, having been working on this without a break (except for eating, sleeping, drinking coffee and smoking) for almost two days now.

**What I have:**

I've got an `UIScrollView` inside my view controller, containing a certain number of textfields and a `UICollectionView`. With a button, I open another view controller for adding new data to the collection view. Back to my first view controller after the new data items have been added, I call `invalidateIntrinsicContentsize` on my `UIScrollView` and on my `UICollectionView` to resize them both to fit their content (I use Autolayout and let both of them hug their content). On both views I've implemented these methods to nicely fit their content, and this part works perfectly fine.

**What my problem is:**

If I add data to the `UICollectionView` in the way just described, and *if I'm in landscape mode*, the problems start: After getting back to my initial view controller and updating the intrinsic content sizes, *the content of my* `UICollectionView` *is displaced* - displaced in such a way, that the scrolling position of the content inside the `UIScrollView` before switching to the data-adding view now becomes something like a fixed content offset. If I scroll up now, I can reach at maximum that position of the content where it has been - by getting scrolled to - before I switched to the data-adding view controller.

**Pictures (everyone loves that):**

To illustrate that situation somehow difficult to explain, I appended two pictures. Red is the entire content area of the scroll view, dark green is the content, where both overlap the color is olive. The visible part of the `UIScrollView` is shown in the highlighted, bordered area.

Before updating the data, content is where it should be:

[image: Normal]
<sub>(source: [grubbrother.com](https://grubbrother.com/wp-content/uploads/before.png))</sub>

After updating the data and updating UI, content is displaced by former scroll position / `contentOffset`:

[image: Not Normal]
<sub>(source: [grubbrother.com](https://grubbrother.com/wp-content/uploads/after.png))</sub>

Please help me with this weird stuff. Unfortunately, I've got a tight deadline and need to move on with the project. Nevertheless I really don't know how to solve this or even what might cause it - I have absolutely no clue.

Comment: Additional Info: Since the displacement occurs only, if the `UIScrollView` has some `contentOffset` before the scene is changed, the bug doesn't occur if I set the `contentOffset` to zero before I switch to the next scene. Nevertheless, I get my problem again If I scroll down by setting `contentOffset` in `viewWillAppear` of my `UIViewController`; but everything is fine if I do that in `viewDidAppear`. This **** is, in a bad manner, totally boggling the mind ...

Answer (score 0):

Despite I couldn't find out yet what causes the problem described in my question, I found a hack around it that at least somehow fixes the symptoms:

As I describe above, the unwanted content displacement that occurs when switching back to the `UIViewController` containg the buggy `UIScrollView` is equal to the `contentOffset` of the `UIscrollView` before switching to another scene.

Knowing this, I set the `contentOffset` to zero after my `UIViewController` disappears.

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [self.scrollView setContentOffset: CGPointZero];
}
```

When the view reappears, I scroll down to the newly added content at the bottom of the `UIScrollView` in question:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (self.appearedFromActorsAdding)
    {
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps anyone running into the same problem.